# idea maven keep creating repeating modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

my idea will automatically keeping creating repeating iml files, and there is always "index updating" process running. Is there a way to prevent this?

[repeating iml files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs25s.jpg)

[maven shows repeating modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb7K6.png)

[idea idexing process keep running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k96bF.png)

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: I got exception in idea log : "Repository not found for root file:///Users/ouke/Desktop/git/cupoo". But actually the directory does exist.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: yes, with different project. I tried clean the cache and restart the app, but doesn't stop it.

Comment: Is it possible to share your sample?